# Why is devicetoken not getting generated for other device?

Tags: android, parse-platform, devicetoken

I am trying to generate device token for 1 device , but why isn't it getting generated for other device.
I am storing that value in parse, Second device token is missing.

[image: Device token]

What is the solution for generating device token for other Device?

Comment: when the app in install in outher device than device tickem genrated

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar , no it is not getting generated. That is the problem.

Comment: may be check your code

Comment: In one mobile it is getting generated, but in other it isn't.

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to GCM device token, then you should know that it takes time for an Android device to generate device token. This process takes place in another thread. So when the device is uploading the data on to your server, the device token might not have generated by your device.